# Is there an open source plugin to mark issue in JIRA based on Findbugs Report?

Tags: java, eclipse, jira, findbugs

I am looking for a tool/plugin for JIRA/Eclipse that can,

1. Execute FindBugs over the code.
2. Based on generated report, provide a UI to mark bug or improvement in JIRA depending on the case. Note that the text should be copied directly from report to marked issue in JIRA.

Looked around on internet but could not find one. Please suggest if such a requirement is fulfilled by any other tool like PMD, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers have suggested that you should create a single task to deal with fixing FindBugs warnings. I'm not even sure that you should do that. The problems identified by FindBugs might not even be problems, and even if they are problems, might have little to no impact on the quality of the system under development. They really should be reviewed by a human instead of blindly added to a bug tracker as something to fix.

My suggestion would be to incorporate FindBugs (and any other static analysis tools) into your build process as well as your code review process. As part of your build process, it would generate reports after every build. As developers work on modules, they would be able to consult the FindBugs reports for those modules and address them as-needed. As part of the code review process, a developer (either the author or a reviewer) can manually launch FindBugs over the code under review, analyze the reports, and include specific issues as action items to handle coming out of the code review using your team's methodology.

That said, if you are using FindBugs 2.0, [there appears to be a JIRA plugin to facilitate what you want to do](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/findbugs2.html#plugins). It appears to have limited support and must be built from source, but it might be something to look at. As I mentioned above, though, I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this really make sense? I mean, creating one JIRA issue for every FindBugs marker will take more time as fixing it immediately in most cases. Not to mention the huge amount of issues in which this will result. The developer will have to spend more time in closing JIRA issues than in fixing them.

I would create exactly one issue for this: "Fix FindBugs warnings before release".

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd use one JIRA Task that says:

"Run FindBugs. Record the report somewhere. Fix the most obvious problems. Run FindBugs again and record the final report." That way everyone can see that work was done, and what work it was.

Storing information about each problem found by FindBugs in a JIRA issue would lead to a large number of issues, and many of them would quickly become outdated.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you can write a script in any language (I would have used python) to Execute FindBugs  and manipulate the generated report in any way you wish and than implement the secod part by using the [Jira remote API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Remote+API+Reference) to create issues or a single issue as others suggested. To pick an API most suited check the manual for your Jira's version to see the full API capabilities.